# Alternative way to set NonStop PERLDB_OPTS

Tags: perl, debugging

I have a perl script, let's call it `test.pl`

I need to run it same way as

```
$ PERLDB_OPTS="NonStop frame=1" perl -d test.pl
```

Since script runs under mod_perl setting PERLDB_OPTS does not work.

I tried to set NonStop options another 3 ways, via `$ENV`, `DB::parse_options` and `.perldb` :

1)

```
$ cat test.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -d
$ENV{'PERLDB_OPTS'} = 'NonStop frame=1';
...
```

2)

```
$ cat test.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -d
DB::parse_options("NonStop=1 frame=1");
...
```

3)

```
$ cat test.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -d
...

$ cat .perldb 
parse_options("NonStop=1 frame=1");
```

But neither worked, output is like when only `-d` option enabled.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Most likely you need to rebuild mod_perl and then enable [Debug Tracing](https://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/debug.html#Debug_Tracing). Maybe your distribution has already built `mod_perl` that way but unless you show us the relevant information, that's hard to tell.